Copy all cell values above a specific string to another sheet
I am trying to copy all cell values in column A above a specific cell value "Question" to another sheet.
The code copies all cell values below the cell value "Question".
Sub CopyBelowData()

    Dim strSearch   As String
    Dim fVal        As Range
    Dim lLastRow    As Long
    Dim strSel      As String
    
    'Set the value you want to search
    strSearch = "*Question*"
    
    'Find string on column A
    Set fVal = Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:A").Find(strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    
    If fVal Is Nothing Then
        'Not Found - end
        MsgBox "Search returned no matches."
        GoTo LastLine
    End If
    
    'Find last used row
    lLastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    strSel = fVal.Address & ":$A$" & lLastRow
    MsgBox "Moving Answer Keys: " & strSel
    
    'Copy and Paste the Answer Key
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range(strSel).Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Columns("A:A").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft

        
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    LastLine:

End Sub


Try
'Set the value you want to search
strSearch = "*Question*"

'Find string on column A
Set fVal = Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:A").Find(strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

If fVal Is Nothing Then
    'Not Found - end
    MsgBox "Search returned no matches."
    GoTo LastLine
End If

lLastRow = fVal.Row - 1  ' We don't want to copy the text "Question", only stuff above
strSel = "A1:A" & lLastRow
MsgBox "Moving Answer Keys: " & strSel

'Copy and Paste the Answer Key
Sheets("Sheet1").Range(strSel).Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Columns("A:A").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft

